# How to test for lossless double / integer conversion?

Tags: c, floating-point, integer, double

I have one double, and one int64_t. I want to know if they hold exactly the same value, and if converting one type into the other does not lose any information.

My current implementation is the following:

```
int int64EqualsDouble(int64_t i, double d) {
    return (d >= INT64_MIN)
        && (d < INT64_MAX)
        && (round(d) == d)
        && (i == (int64_t)d);
}
```

**My question is: is this implementation correct? And if not, what would be a correct answer?** To be correct, it must leave no false positive, and no false negative.

Some sample inputs:

- int64EqualsDouble(0, 0.0) should return 1
- int64EqualsDouble(1, 1.0) should return 1
- int64EqualsDouble(0x3FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF, (double)0x3FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF) should return 0, because 2^62 - 1 can be exactly represented with int64_t, but not with double.
- int64EqualsDouble(0x4000000000000000, (double)0x4000000000000000) should return 1, because 2^62 can be exactly represented in both int64_t and double.
- int64EqualsDouble(INT64_MAX, (double)INT64_MAX) should return 0, because INT64_MAX can not be exactly represented as a double
- int64EqualsDouble(..., 1.0e100) should return 0, because 1.0e100 can not be exactly represented as an int64_t.

Comment: Your code doesn't seem unreasonable to me. Assuming a sane floating-point environment anyway, in the absence of `__STDC_IEC_559__` guarantees all bets are off and you'll probably need to resort to platform-specific hacks.

Comment: You could probably use `frexp, frexpf, frexpl` functions that deconstruct  floating-point number to fractional and integral components then compare the integral component and zero exponen.

Comment: tangential question: the specification of `round` includes "The round functions round their argument to the nearest integer value". What happens for numbers which aren't integers but the nearest integer value is not exactly representible? (Are there any such values?)

Comment: @M.M There are none, as long a `x` is finite.  "integers" for `round()` refers to the mathematical sense, not the members of some integer type like `intmax_t`.

Comment: @chux I mean, maybe there is a situation such as the exactly representible numbers going 100001.34, 100002.56, 100003.78  , and if so, what does `round(100002.56)` give

Comment: @M.M Finite floating point numbers _always_ have magnitudes values like `a(i)*pow(FLT_RADIX,i) + a(i-1)*pow(FLT_RADIX,i-1) + a(i-2)*pow(FLT_RADIX,i-2) ...` where coefficient `a(j)` is in the integer range [0...FLT_RADIX-1].   To "floor" such a number to an integer, drop all terms where `i-j` is negative.  To "ceiling" any of these numbers with a negative `i-j` term can have 1 added to to the "floor" value.  Numbers without a negative `i-j` are all ready integers.  IOWs "exactly representable FP numbers going 100001.34, 100002.56, 100003.78" cannot exist as they do not fit floating point form.

Comment: I would suggest to use this instead: `return (double)i == d && i == (int64_t)d;` in precisely this order. If the first condition succeeds, it is certain that `d` can actually be represented as an `uint64_t`. However, it may have been compared to a rounded `i`, so that first condition is not sufficient. That's what the second condition is there to check. Since `d` has been proven to be exactly representable, the cast is lossless, and the result of the comparison true to the exact values of both arguments.

Comment: Thanks @cmaster. I could not find any counter-example.

Comment: int32 to double conversion is always [lossless](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63244349/5447906). But, of course, it is not true for int64.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, your solution works correctly because it was designed to do so, because `int64_t` is represented in two's complement by definition (C99 7.18.1.1:1), on platforms that use something resembling binary IEEE 754 double-precision for the `double` type. It is basically the same as [this one](http://gynvael.coldwind.pl/?id=535).

Under these conditions:

- `d < INT64_MAX` is correct because it is equivalent to `d < (double) INT64_MAX` and in the conversion to double, the number `INT64_MAX`, equal to 0x7fffffffffffffff, rounds up. Thus you want `d` to be strictly less than the resulting `double` to avoid triggering UB when executing `(int64_t)d`.
- On the other hand, `INT64_MIN`, being -0x8000000000000000, is exactly representable, meaning that a `double` that is equal to `(double)INT64_MIN` can be equal to some `int64_t` and should not be excluded (and such a `double` can be converted to `int64_t` without triggering undefined behavior)

It goes without saying that since we have specifically used the assumptions about 2's complement for integers and binary floating-point, the correctness of the code is not guaranteed by this reasoning on platforms that differ. Take a platform with binary 64-bit floating-point and a 64-bit 1's complement integer type `T`. On that platform `T_MIN` is `-0x7fffffffffffffff`. The conversion to `double` of that number rounds down, resulting in `-0x1.0p63`. On that platform, using your program as it is written, using `-0x1.0p63` for `d` makes the first three conditions true, resulting in undefined behavior in `(T)d`, because [overflow in the conversion from integer to floating-point is undefined behavior](http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2013/10/09/Overflow-float-integer).

---

If you have access to full IEEE 754 features, there is a shorter solution:

```
#include <fenv.h>
…
#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON
feclearexcept(FE_INEXACT), f == i && !fetestexcept(FE_INEXACT)
```

This solution takes advantage of the conversion from integer to floating-point setting the INEXACT flag iff the conversion is inexact (that is, if `i` is not representable exactly as a `double`).

The INEXACT flag remains unset and `f` is equal to `(double)i` if and only if `f` and `i` represent the same mathematical value in their respective types.

This approach requires the compiler to have been warned that the code accesses the FPU's state, normally with `#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS on` but that's typically not supported and you have to use a compilation flag instead.

Comment: You felt the need to add the "on platforms that use 2's complement for integers and something resembling binary IEEE 754 for floating-point" precision on your initial answer. So... It looks like you're not quite as sure as you sound, or that my question is badly written.

Comment: The context is SQlite, BTW. This database may store numerical values as doubles, or int64. My own users may give me doubles or int64. The question I want to answer is the following: "Given the value that I know is already stored in the database, and this new value you give me in, is an UPDATE statement actually necessary in order to persist the new value?". Int/int comparison is trivial, so is double/double. Remains the Double/Int comparison :-)

Comment: Can you explain why would integer implementation mattered here. Because of negative zero? Isn't -0 == 0.0 true?

Comment: 1/ I am sure. It is my job to approach the properties that programs have or do not have as theorems, and theorems have hypotheses. If the platform is not two's complement, then your first two conditions may be subtly wrong, and if it's not ieee 754-style binary floating-point, all bets are off. Stating hypotheses doesn't make one unsure, and if you think the correlation goes this way I have a bridge to sell you.

Comment: @this `d < INT64_MAX` is correct because it is equivalent to `d < (double) INT64_MAX` and that in the conversion to `double`, **assuming 2's complement**, the number `INT64_MAX` rounds **up** in that conversion. Thus you want `d` to be strictly less than the rsulting double to avoid triggering UB on `(int64_t)d`.

Comment: @this OTOH, still assuming 2's complement, `INT64_MIN` is exactly representable, meaning that a double that is equal to `(double)INT64_MIN` can be equal to an `int64_t` and should not be excluded (and can be converted to `int64_t` without triggering UB).

Comment: @this All this reasoning assumes binary IEEE 754-like floating-point in addition to 2's complement for integers because otherwise `INT64_MAX` may not round up when converted and `INT64_MIN` may not be exactly representable.

Comment: @PascalCuoq I see. Thank you.

Comment: @GwendalRoué One thing that's not clear about your question is whether you want to know if it's correct on any platform (and in this case the answer is no: take a platform with binary 64-bit floating-point and 1's complement, and your program triggers UB in `(int64_t)d` each time `d` has been assigned with `d = (double) INT64_MIN;` before invoking your code) or whether it's correct on the usual 2's complement IEEE 754 floating-point platform (yes).

Comment: @PascalCuoq: Yes, I wanted to avoid overflow and this is why I used < INT64_MAX and >= INT64_MIN. Thanks for the explanations on those conditions, and their implicit reliance on 2's complement, which I was not getting well.

Comment: @GwendalRoué What is “typically not supported” is `#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS`, but compilers usually provide other means to write code that accesses the FPU state, so that the qualification “typically not supported” does not apply to the solution.

Comment: @PascalCuoq I forgot that intN_t types are defined to be two's complement anyway.

Comment: The answer makes the reasonable assumption the the precision of `double` is less than about 64-bit.  Yet is `double` had 64-ish bits of precision, code should be `&& (d <= INT64_MAX)`  `<=` vs `<`.  Hmmm see something like this mentioned in [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33719132/how-to-test-for-lossless-double-integer-conversion#comment55286426_33754329)

Comment: @chux I have made the reference to IEEE 754 double-precision more explicit, to avoid saying something false. I hope that a reader that would have a `double` type that could represent exactly `INT64_MIN` and `INT64_MAX` would infer from the reasoning that then `<=` is appropriate for both tests.

Comment: @Olaf : I have evidence for mandatory two's complement encoding of int64_t at https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/C_Reference/stdint.h

Answer (score 3):

OP's code has a dependency that can be avoided.

For a successful compare, `d` must be a whole number and `round(d) == d` takes care of that.  Even `d`, as a NaN would fail that.

`d` must be *mathematically* in the range of [`INT64_MIN` ... `INT64_MAX`] and if the `if` conditions properly insure that, then the final `i == (int64_t)d` completes the test.

So the question comes down to comparing `INT64` limits with the `double` `d`.

Let us assume `FLT_RADIX == 2`, but not necessarily [IEEE 754 binary64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format).

`d >= INT64_MIN` is not a problem as `-INT64_MIN` is a power of 2 and exactly converts to a `double` of the same value, so the `>=` is exact.

Code would like to do the mathematical `d <= INT64_MAX`, but that may not work and so a problem.  `INT64_MAX` is a "power of 2 - 1" and *may* not convert exactly - it depends on if the precision of the `double` exceeds 63 bits - rendering the compare unclear.  A solution is to halve the comparison.  `d/2` suffers no precision loss and `INT64_MAX/2 + 1` converts exactly to a `double` power-of-2

```
d/2 < (INT64_MAX/2 + 1)
```

[Edit]

```
// or simply
d < ((double)(INT64_MAX/2 + 1))*2
```

---

Thus if code does not want to rely on the `double` having less precision than `uint64_t`.  (Something that likely applies with `long double`) a more portable solution would be

```
int int64EqualsDouble(int64_t i, double d) {
    return (d >= INT64_MIN)
        && (d < ((double)(INT64_MAX/2 + 1))*2)  // (d/2 < (INT64_MAX/2 + 1))
        && (round(d) == d)
        && (i == (int64_t)d);
}
```

Note: No rounding mode issues.

[Edit] Deeper limit explanation

Insuring  mathematically, `INT64_MIN <= d <= INT64_MAX`, can be re-stated as `INT64_MIN <= d < (INT64_MAX + 1)` as we are dealing with whole numbers.  Since the raw application of `(double) (INT64_MAX + 1)` in code is certainly 0, an alternative, is `((double)(INT64_MAX/2 + 1))*2`.  This can be extended for rare machines with `double` of higher powers-of-2 to `((double)(INT64_MAX/FLT_RADIX + 1))*FLT_RADIX`.  The comparison limits being *exact* powers-of-2, conversion to `double` suffers no precision loss and `(lo_limit >= d) && (d < hi_limit)` is exact, regardless of the precision of the floating point.  Note: that a rare floating point with `FLT_RADIX == 10` is still a problem.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Pascal Cuoq's elaborate answer, and given the extra context you give in comments, I would add a test for negative zeros.  You should preserve negative zeros unless you have good reasons not to.  You need a specific test to avoid converting them to `(int64_t)0`. With your current proposal, negative zeros will pass your test, get stored as `int64_t` and read back as positive zeros.

I am not sure what is the most efficient way to test them, maybe this:

```
int int64EqualsDouble(int64_t i, double d) {
    return (d >= INT64_MIN)
        && (d < INT64_MAX)
        && (round(d) == d)
        && (i == (int64_t)d
        && (!signbit(d) || d != 0.0);
}
```

Comment: Hello @chqrlie. Thanks for pointing negative zero, which has been overlooked until your contribution. "According to the IEEE 754 standard, negative zero and positive zero should compare as equal with the usual (numerical) comparison operators, like the == operators of C." (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero): it's hard to tell whether the int64EqualsDouble function should ignore negative zero or not. The "converting one type into the other does not lose any information" part of the question requires it, though. +1