# how do i round a float to an int?

Tags: c, math

say i have:

```
55.3 and want 55
55.6 and want 56
81.1 and want 81
etc.
```

i have been trying to use the `round()` function but it seems to keep giving me the highest value for all decimal places.

Comment: See http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_floor.htm

Comment: "it seems to keep giving me the highest value for all decimal places" - what do you mean by this?

Comment: I am storing the values in a float x variable and when i do round(x) , it will just give me the next highest int of all

Comment: If you have been trying something, the prudent thing to do is post the code for this.  It may be the way you're using it.

Answer (score 3):

OP has not posted code that failed.  Certain OP coded incorrectly.

Using `round()` is *the* correct way to round a `double` before converting to an `int`.  Of course it must be in range.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <assert.h>

int round_to_int(double x) {
  x = round(x);
  assert(x >= INT_MIN);
  assert(x < (INT_MAX/2 + 1)*2.0);
  return (int) x;
}
```

See [How to test for lossless double / integer conversion?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33719132/2410359) for details about the `assert()`s.

Why not use `(int)(x + 0.5);`?

1) It fails for negative numbers.

2) It can fail for the `double` just smaller than `0.5` as the `x + 0.5` can round to `1.0`.

3) When the precision of `int` exceeds `double`, values where the least significant bit is 0.5 or 1.0, `x+0.5` may *round* to the next integer.

4) Unadorned, it has no range checking.

Answer (score 2):

In the olden days we used to say `int the_int = (int)(some_double + 0.5);` (obviously beware if you are dealing with negative values too).

Comment: Any explanation why `round()` wouldn't work?

Comment: @juanchopanza No - `round()` should work. I think it used to be to avoid bringing in -lm but I could be wrong - perhaps someone thought it was faster that `round()`

Comment: `(int)(some_double + 0.5)` fails for many numbers whose unit-in-last-place is 0.5 or 1.  - these may be beyond `INT_MAX`.  It also fails for the `double` just less than 0.5.

Comment: OP claims `round()` doesn't work. It is in the question.

Comment: @juanchopanza OP hasn't provided us enough info to know if/why `round()` doesn't work (short answer: `round()` works, OP's use of it or understanding of it is wrong ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Increase the magnitude by one half and truncate:

```
int round_up_or_down(double x)
{
    return x > 0 ? x + 0.5 : x - 0.5;
}
```

This distributes the real intervals uniformly:

- ...
- `[-1.5, -0.5) => -1`
- `[-0.5, +0.5) =>  0`
- `[+0.5, +1.5) -> +1`
- ...

Comment: [Demo](https://ideone.com/Ae0xVj)

Comment: But what is wrong with `round()`?

Comment: @juanchopanza: Nothing, `round` is fine -- it has a different symmetry from this formula, though (`round` has reflection symmetry around 0, mine has translation symmetry).